# What is the best way to implement Dialogflow v2 webhook in Java

Tags: dialogflow-es

I would like to know what is the best way to implement a dialogflow v2 webhook in Java because there are several libraries available today.

I have identified the following libraries:

- Dialogflow API Client Library for Java :
  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/dialogflow/v2
- Google Cloud Java Client for Dialogflow : 
  https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-dialogflow
- Actions on Google Java/Kotlin Client Library :
  https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-java

I already had a good experience with Dialogflow API Client Library for Java, which facilitates the creation of rich message. But is it really the best choice?

What is the best solution in terms of:

- features (rich message,...)
- practicality
- durability
- performance

Edit: 
After some test, Actions on Google Java/Kotlin Client Library seems to be the best choice in terms of features and is very good in practicality for Google Actions.

Using the ResponseBuilder you can achieve things the same way as Dialogflow API Client Library for Java.

```
 ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = getResponseBuilder(request);
 WebhookResponse webhookResponse$actions_on_google = new WebhookResponse();
 List<IntentMessage> fulfillmentMessages = Lists.newArrayList();
 IntentMessage im = new IntentMessage();
 IntentMessageQuickReplies qr = new IntentMessageQuickReplies();
 List<String> l = Lists.newArrayList();
        l.add("a");
        l.add("b");
        l.add("c");
 qr.setQuickReplies(l);
 im.setQuickReplies(qr);
 fulfillmentMessages.add(im);        
 webhookResponse$actions_on_google.setFulfillmentMessages(fulfillmentMessages);
responseBuilder.setWebhookResponse$actions_on_google(webhookResponse$actions_on_google);
```

Comment: Are you building an action for the Google Assistant? If so, the Actions on Google Java/Kotlin client library is your best option. You can learn more [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/).

Comment: Hello, I'm not specifically building an action at the moment, but I want to be as generic as possible so I can do it when it will be the  right time. However, what I found interesting in the "Actions on Google Java/Kotlin Client Library" is the @ForIntent annotation.
There is a Medium post on the subject : https://medium.com/google-developers/announcing-the-java-kotlin-client-library-for-actions-on-google-217828dead